# jquery click change background image url function

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the background image url within the parent row when the selected color is select. When click on the first col pink, the first col background image will change to pink and for the second col click on white, the second col will change to white without affect the first col.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  
$(".selector a").change(function(){
    if ('.image-black').hasClass('selected'){
     $(".image").css("background-image", "url(https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/black.jpg)");
} else {
     if ('.image-white').hasClass('selected'){
   $(".image").css("background-image", "url(https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/white.jpg)");
     } else {
          if ('.image--pink').hasClass('selected'){
          $(".image").css("background-image", "url(https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pink.jpg)");
          }
     }
}
});
  
});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/white.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="selector">
      <a href="#" class="image-black selected">Black</a>
      <a href="#" class="image-white">White</a>
      <a href="#" class="image-pink">Pink</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url(https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/white.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="selector">
      <a href="#" class="image-black selected">Black</a>
      <a href="#" class="image-white">White</a>
      <a href="#" class="image-pink">Pink</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1so3mwbr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$(".selector a").click(function(){
        $(".selector a").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
         var className = $(this).attr('class').split('-')[1].split(' ')[0];

        $(".image").css("background-image", "url(https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/"+className+".jpg)");

});

});
```

Comment: sorry but it still not working, the background-image is as below


https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/white.jpg

https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/black.jpg

https://cottontee.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/pink.jpg

Comment: I edited my answer and tested it, please try again, I think this solution is general and reuse

Comment: did you test my new answer? I think it's a general solution and works for the number of images.

Comment: sorry what is there is 2 column? I did not update the jsfiddle this is the latest version.

https://jsfiddle.net/1so3mwbr/9/